# Clearcase multisite sync issue

Tags: clearcase

I am stuck with an issue with clearcase multisite syncing of a particular vob. I have already tried multitool chepoch on the master replica (say, M) to retrieve epoch table entries from remote replica (say, R). e.g. mt chepoch -actual R@vob-path. I understand that after this the master should start exporting packets as per the epoch table of remote (or something like that).

I have also tried using recoverpacket from master. e.g. mt recoverpacket -since <\last successful import date from lshistory of the vob on R> R@vob-path . This too, as I understand, is another way to 'sync' the epoch tables from remote to master by specifying a date.

All solutions on the internet including IBM's support website point to the same solutions that I just mentioned. The general idea is: get the epoch table on Master to match the Remote and let clearcase do the rest.

The problem is that the vob on the remote replica is WAYYY behind the master. So master keeps exporting packets and remote keeps storing them in the incoming bay, where they accumulate to several Gb. The scheduled sync_receive job fails to import these packets saying "packet depends on changes not yet received". But these changes never actually arrive from the master.

I have started to suspect that the master is not sending packets older than some point, which is why incoming bay of my remote keeps storing the 'newer' ones.

Is there anything else that I can try here?

Help is MUCH appreciated!

Thanks

Aashish.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination vob (remote replica) is somehow corrupted, one workaround would be to **re-create** said remote replica Vob, following a process similar to "[How to move a VOB using ClearCase MultiSite](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266219)", in order to re-export the all vob to a brand new replica.

That would involve a [`cleartool mkreplica -export/import`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_mkreplica.htm).

Comment: I can't afford to mess-up the existing vob for now. But let's say I  exported using mkreplica (or similar) and created a new 'copy' on remote but with a different name, will I ever be able to replace the existing one with this new copy? Whatever I do, there is no way I can afford to lose the hard work (changes) that remote's users have made to the vob.

Comment: @AashishSharma yes (validate the idea with IBM support). I have exported many vobs that way, even recreating  new replica on the remote side, when I was unsure of the state of the existing replica: both co-exist now on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the command to type in your site is:

```
multitool chepoch -actual replica:{remote-replica}@{vob-tag}
```

Followed by a "`multitool syncreplica -export`" command

I recommend something like

```
multitool  syncreplica -export -max 500m -out {packet-name} {replica-name}@{vob-tag}
```

I recommend to use the `-max` option in case there are too many data to replicate. This will avoid the creation of a 5Gb packet for example.
The `-out` option is useful as well because the packet will be generated but not shipped to the remote ship. By doing so, you can check if the sync paquet is actually created or not. If the packet is created, you can then transfer it to the remote site using the [`mkorder`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237200) command

The main reason why a packet would not be generated is because the oplog has been scrubbed.
By default, I remember the oplogs older than 180 days (data to confirm) are scrubbed and are not kept forever. You should check the file `/usr/atria/config/vob/vob_scrubber_params` on your VOB server in order to check how long your oplogs are kept.
See IBM doc about [scrubbing](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0620/SGI_Admin/books/ClrC_AG/sgi_html/ch10.html)

If you do have a 3rd site, and if your server has been scrubbed, you can try to generate the packet from the 3rd site.

Last resort is indeed to recreate the replica, as suggested by VonC.